# Identity regarding the components of a dual basis

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, tensors, general-relativity

This problem is from Robert Wald's "General Relativity."  The problem is 4(b) from chapter 2.  Let $Y_1\cdots Y_n$ be smooth vector fields on an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ such that at each $p\in M$ they form a basis of the tangent space $V_p$.  Then we expand the Lie bracket in this basis.
$$ [Y_\alpha,Y_\beta]=C^{\gamma}_{~~~ \alpha\beta}Y_{\gamma}$$
Where $C^{\gamma}_{~~~ \alpha\beta}=-C^{\gamma}_{~~~ \beta\alpha}$.  Now, let $Y^{1^*}\cdots Y^{n^*}$ be the dual basis.  I am asked to show that the components of the dual basis satisfy the following identity.
$$\partial_\nu (Y^{\gamma^*})_\mu-\partial_\mu (Y^{\gamma^*})_\nu = C^{\gamma}_{~~~ \alpha\beta}(Y^{\alpha^*})_\mu(Y^{\beta^*})_\nu$$
The hint to contract both sides of the equation with $(Y_\sigma)^\mu(Y_\rho)^\nu$ was given, and I did it.  This just left me with the identity
$$C^{\gamma}_{~~~ \sigma\rho} = \left[ \partial_\nu (Y^{\gamma^*})_\mu-\partial_\mu (Y^{\gamma^*})_\nu\right] (Y_\sigma)^\mu(Y_\rho)^\nu. $$
However, I am stuck after this short step.  I've tried messing around with that identity and haven't gotten anywhere with it.  Could someone give some hints?

Comment: Maybe start from the RHS of the equation you would like to show and plug in the expression you have derived for the C's...

Comment: @Heterotic I tried that but couldn't get anywhere...just a big mess